# How do you resolve a supply voltage high warning on an optical SFP in a router?

Tags: networking, router, voltage

Here is the error showing in my log file on an Alcatel router:

```
5629 2012/01/15 02:41:24.81 EST MINOR: PORT #2030 Base Port 1/2/8
"XFP/SFP DDM (supplyVoltage-high-warning) raised"
```

When I issue the show port command these are the details provided regarding the voltage:

```
===============================================================================
Transceiver Digital Diagnostic Monitoring (DDM), Externally Calibrated
===============================================================================
                              Value High Alarm  High Warn   Low Warn  Low Alarm
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Supply Voltage (V)             3.51      3.60       3.50!      3.10      3.00
```

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. There is a corresponding error, but you're not getting that error. So you don't need to resolve any error. Was anything going on at that time? Were you swapping SFPs or something?

Comment: nothing occurred at that time it happened around 2:41 am according to the timestamp no one was working at that time

Comment: The voltage got higher than the SFP believes it should have gotten, but not higher than the SFP is designed to tolerate. There's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a sign that the optics are going bad. The voltage was causing an increased transmission level and was also causing a high optical power alarm.  Replacing them fixed the issue.